# Export/import from local PostGIS db to cartodb?

Tags: postgis, carto

I have a local PostGIS database with a polygon table and a nonspatial table. I would like to upload them into my CartoDB account. What is the best way to do this? I could export the polygon layer as a shp and the nonspatial table as a csv then upload them like that, is that the most straightforward way? Or is there a way to skip that and copy directly from postgis to postgis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used the following:

1) Export as a .SHP, zipped, then imported

2) Using GDAL / OGR2OGR as per Paul Ramsey's blog post:

http://blog.cartodb.com/data-sync-ogr/

- this option will allow you to connect directly from your PostGIS table, and run the GDAL command to truncate and load your data...

3) The [CartoDB QGIS Plugin](http://blog.cartodb.com/qgis-plugin/) will now allow you to upload data to your CartoDB account from QGIS

Comment: Thanks. The ogr2ogr seems like a good option if you want to set up a regular update process.

Comment: @kmack added a new one - the CartoDB QGIS plugin now supports uploading tables to your cartodb account through QGIS